# Gnome 3 custom keybinds with xdotool

Tags: gnome

I use `xdotool` to created a simple keyboard shortcut:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ name
'Test'
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ binding
'F3'
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ command
'test.sh'
```

-----

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

VAR1="Test123@"

sleep 0.5; xdotool type --clearmodifiers "$VAR1"
```

The problem is that the `at` symbol is quite often missing from the output - is it because it's a special character or I'm doing something wrong?

```
$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 21 (Twenty One)
$ xdotool --version
xdotool version 2.20110530.1
```

Comment: Is it just random or do you have dependency on what application do you paste into? Like terminal or text editor.

Comment: It's random but it happens more often on the terminal.

Comment: Can you test it with just `xdotool type '@'` and `xdotool key 'shift+2'`?

Comment: `xdotool type '@'` - similar issue, `xdotool key 'shift+2'` - I'm not sure if I can test this one because I'm using `gb` keymap where `@ = shift+' (single quote)`

Comment: Can you try to add `setxkbmap gb` to your script before running xdottool?

Comment: I also found that there was an issue with that symbol, but it should be fixed [link](https://code.google.com/p/semicomplete/issues/detail?id=21)

Comment: `xdotool type --clearmodifiers "Test123" && xdotool key --clearmodifiers "at"` - this works fine so far, thanks